# Parsing current activity to functions in android studio

Tags: android, android-activity, permissions

I want to get read and write rights on the external storage. Therefore I need to give an activity as parameter.

In the Android tutorial and on Stackoverflow the common answer is to use the keyword. I use this https://github.com/tbruyelle/RxPermissions as I read that it is commonly used to make things easier.

```java
this
```

or

```java
myActivity.this
```

and on fragment

```java
getActivity()
```

none of these seem to work and I get can't resolve Activity. Or in the Debug that he cannot cast the activity to fragment

Here is my Class:

```java
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
...
...
private void grantPermissions() {
        new RxPermissions(WebViewActivity)
                .request(Manifest.permission_group.STORAGE) // ask single or multiple permission once
                .subscribe( new Consumer<Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Boolean granted) throws Exception {
                        if (granted) {
                            // All requested permissions are granted
                        } else {
                            // At least one permission is denied
                        }
                    }
                } );
    }
}
```

How can I parse my activity, am I missing a step?

Thanks for help

---

### Found the solution. I had to clear my cashe.... that was the only reason it was not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
new RxPermissions(WebViewActivity)
```

You need to use:

```
new RxPermissions(this)
```

Comment: yes and exactly that is not working. When I hover over ```this``` it says can't resolve ....WebViewActivity. Even though in a different function it's working without any problem.

Comment: Post the entire code of `WebViewActivity` please (or provide a link to it or something). This sounds like a syntax/parsing problem. LIke a semicolon in the wrong place. Don't try to post the code in a comment. Just edit your question and put it there, or provide an URL where we can get the code.